# how to infinite scroll and scrap at the same time

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, automation

I'm new to automation and puppeteer

i want to infinite scroll the data in Google Maps query i do scrolling first untill it cant anymore,then click that card link 1 by 1 but the loaded data gets restarted and need to scroll again which makes my code break and only print 8 data card

what i want to achieve is while it scraps 1 by 1 it scrolls to the scraped card location and wait for new data if we are at last item and continues scrap again from the previous position after load data are there

I already try this

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import puppeteer from "puppeteer-core";
import { executablePath } from "puppeteer";

const scrollableDivSelector =
  "div.m6QErb.DxyBCb.kA9KIf.dS8AEf.ecceSd > div[role ='feed']";
const scrollDistance = 1000;

async function infiniteScroll(page, selector, distance) {
  let previousScrollHeight = 0;
  let currentScrollHeight = -1;

  while (previousScrollHeight !== currentScrollHeight) {
    previousScrollHeight = currentScrollHeight;

    await page.evaluate(
      (selector, distance) => {
        const div = document.querySelector(selector);
        if (div) {
          div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;
        }
      },
      selector,
      distance
    );

    await page.waitForTimeout(5000);

    currentScrollHeight = await page.evaluate((selector) => {
      const div = document.querySelector(selector);
      return div ? div.scrollHeight : 0;
    }, selector);
  }
}

export async function GET(request, res) {
  const before = Date.now();

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    executablePath: executablePath(),
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  try {
    await page.goto("https://www.google.com/maps");
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1080, height: 1024 });
    await page.type("[name='q']", "cafe di jakarta");
    page.keyboard.press("Enter");

    await page.waitForSelector("div.Nv2PK.THOPZb.CpccDe");
    await page.waitForSelector("div.m6QErb.DxyBCb.kA9KIf.dS8AEf.ecceSd");

    await infiniteScroll(page, scrollableDivSelector, scrollDistance);

    const itemElements = await page.$$("div.Nv2PK.THOPZb.CpccDe");

    for (const itemElement of itemElements) {
      await page.waitForSelector("a.hfpxzc");
      const link = await itemElement.$("a.hfpxzc");
      if (link) {
        await link.click();
        await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });
        await page.waitForSelector("h1.DUwDvf.lfPIob");

        const scrapedData = [];

        let nama_tempat =
          (await page.$eval(
            "h1.DUwDvf.lfPIob",
            (element) => element.textContent
          )) || "NULL";

        let jenis =
          (await page.$eval(
            "button.DkEaL",
            (element) => element.textContent
          )) || "NULL";

        let ratings =
          (await page.$$eval("button.F7nice > span", (elements) =>
            elements.map((element) => element.textContent)
          )) || "NULL";

     
        scrapedData.push(nama_tempat, jenis, ratings);

        console.log(scrapedData);
        await page.goBack();
      } else {
        console.log("Link not found or element is detached.");
      }
    }

    console.log(itemElements.length);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("An error occurred:", error);
  } finally {
    // await browser.close();
  }

  const after = Date.now();
  console.log((after - before) / 1000);

  return NextResponse.json({ hi: "hello" });
}
```